# How to browse anonymously?

Tags: orbot, android

I'm new to this sort of thing and its difficult to grasp the whole thing especially since I'm on android.

All I want to do is browse without my Internet provider or anyone else from being able to see it at least easily. I just got into this stuff today so I'm just wondering how I would be able to go about that. (I have orbot installed and ready to use with VPN on)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use [Orfox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.orfox) for browsing, it's designed to use Tor. It doesn't have *all* the protections of Tor Browser yet but it's the best currently available and eventually intends to mirror all of the same protections against fingerprinting and tracking.

Comment: One more question. If I enable VPN and tell orbot to work for orfox browser anytime I tell orbot  to turn on that's it then right?

Comment: Three ways, turn on vpn, start orbit, then load orfox.  Or just use VPN without orbit/orfox or Use orbot+rfox

Comment: Orfox doesn't need the VPN mode to work, it just needs Orbot to be running. If Orbot isn't running, it simply won't connect.

Comment: @cacahuatl hi I turn on VPN just on Case but I clicked orfox and it brang me to a link saying that its working but thanks for the info!

Comment: I think it's sensible to use VPN mode for it aswell, as an extra layer of protection against any leaks, malicious or otherwise.

Comment: Try this https://connectwww.com/how-to-stay-anonymous-in-kali-linux-penetration-testing-install-and-configure-proxychains-and-tor-for-anonymity/5264/, it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You best option is probably to use Orfox paired with the latest version of Orbot.

This is the most recommended setup since other browsers might make you vulnerable against fingerprinting and tracking methods, you don't have to worry about using Orfox.